# resultset to json using gson

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets, gson

If I have table like this:

```
MsUser
  - userID
  - username

MsProject
  - userID
  - ProjectID
  - ProjectName
```

If I have query like this:

```
Result set = select * from MsUser mu, MsProject mp WHERE mu.userID = mp.userID
```

Can I convert resultset from query above to JSON using `Google gson`?
Btw I using JSP to develop my application.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this method to convert `ResultSet` object to `jsonArray`.

```
public static JSONArray convertToJSON(ResultSet resultSet)
            throws Exception {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int total_columns = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < total_columns; i++) {
                obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1).toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
            }
          jsonArray.put(obj);
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

If you want to convert this jsonArray to json object then use the method below,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("arrayName",jsonArray);
```

**Update:** To convert ResultSet in json object we need to use [org.json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/org.json/org.json.jar.zip) jar.you should download and added to your project class-path.