# MySQL ResultSet into Gson array

Tags: json, java-8, gson

I want to put a MySQL result set into a JsonArray using Gsons library. How can I best achieve this. I've read this:
[resultset to json using gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562487/resultset-to-json-using-gson)

But it uses for some reason, the simple-Json library in addition. i dont want that if possible. Is there any way to achieve this easily with the gson library?

Thank you very much!

PlayerList.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package de.freakyonline.ucone;

import de.freakyonline.ucone.Player;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author uwe
 */
public class PlayerList {

    ObservableList<Player> playerList;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    Socket sock;
    private Object obj = null;
    private Object obj2 = null;
    TextArea consoleOneTextArea;

    public PlayerList(ObjectInputStream in, ObjectOutputStream out, Socket sock, TextArea consoleOneTextArea) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
        this.sock = sock;
        this.consoleOneTextArea = consoleOneTextArea;
        getPlayersFromServer();
    }

    private void getPlayersFromServer() {

/*        try {
            out.writeObject("getplayers");
            obj=in.readObject();

            if(obj == null) { 
                System.out.println("ERROR! void getPlayersFromServer in PlayerList.java");
                Platform.exit(); 
            }

            String command = obj.toString().toLowerCase();
            String currentFromServer;

            if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("getplayers")) { 
                while((obj2=in.readObject()) != null) {
                    currentFromServer = obj2.toString().toLowerCase();

                    for(String cell : currentFromServer.split(" ")) {
                        System.out.println(cell.toString());                           
                    }


                    if (currentFromServer.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                        consoleOneTextArea.appendText("This is finished. Have fun!\n");
                        break;
                    }

                    consoleOneTextArea.appendText(currentFromServer + "\n");
                }

            } { System.out.println("ERROR"); }
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
*/

        this.playerList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Player("freakyy85","Owner","1810",31,"m", "missing..."),
        new Player("Ky3ak","Owner","1920",34,"m", "missing...")
        );
    }
}
```

(ive commented out some parts, as they are not relevant anymore)

Player.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package de.freakyonline.ucone;

import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author uwe
 */
public class Remote implements Runnable {
    private Object obj = null;
    private Object obj2 = null;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private Socket sock;

    private TextArea consoleOneTextArea;

    public Remote (ObjectInputStream in, ObjectOutputStream out, Socket sock) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
        this.sock = sock;
    }

    public ObjectInputStream getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    public ObjectOutputStream getOut() {
        return out;
    }

    public Socket getSock() {
        return sock;
    }

    public void setConsoleOneTextArea(TextArea consoleOneTextArea) {
        this.consoleOneTextArea = consoleOneTextArea;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while((obj=in.readObject()) != null && sock.isConnected()) {
                String command = obj.toString().toLowerCase();
                String currentFromServer;

                switch(command) {
                    case "getplayers": 
/*                      while((obj2=in.readObject()) != null) {
                            currentFromServer = obj2.toString().toLowerCase();

                            if (currentFromServer.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                                consoleOneTextArea.appendText("This is finished. Have fun!\n");
                                break;
                            }

                            consoleOneTextArea.appendText(currentFromServer + "\n");
*/                        }

                        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));




                        jsonReader.close();

                        break;
                }
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve this easily with the gson library?

Not really. Gson and JDBC are too/two unrelated things so you have to implement a custom remapping function to "decode" JDBC result set rows/fields and "encode" them back to JSON array/object respectively. Accumulating a `JsonArray` instance may be expensive from the memory consumption point of view, or even crash the application with `OutOfMemoryError` for huge result sets. Nonetheless they are good if the result sets are known to be small or `LIMIT`ed.

#### Accumulating JsonArray

```java
static JsonArray resultSetToJsonArray(final ResultSet resultSet)
        throws SQLException {
    final ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
    // JsonArray is a Gson built-in class to hold JSON arrays
    final JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    while ( resultSet.next() ) {
        jsonArray.add(resultSetRowToJsonObject(resultSet, metaData));
    }
    return jsonArray;
}

private static JsonElement resultSetRowToJsonObject(final ResultSet resultSet, final ResultSetMetaData metaData)
        throws SQLException {
    final int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    // Every result set row is a JsonObject equivalent
    final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    // JDBC uses 1-based loops
    for ( int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
        jsonObject.add(metaData.getColumnName(i), fieldToJsonElement(resultSet, metaData, i));
    }
    return jsonObject;
}

private static JsonElement fieldToJsonElement(final ResultSet resultSet, final ResultSetMetaData metaData, final int column)
        throws SQLException {
    final int columnType = metaData.getColumnType(column);
    final Optional<JsonElement> jsonElement;
    // Process each SQL type mapping a value to a JSON tree equivalent
    switch ( columnType ) {
    case Types.BIT:
    case Types.TINYINT:
    case Types.SMALLINT:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO: " + JDBCType.valueOf(columnType));
    case Types.INTEGER:
        // resultSet.getInt() returns 0 in case of null, so it must be extracted with getObject and cast, then converted to a JsonPrimitive
        jsonElement = Optional.ofNullable((Integer) resultSet.getObject(column)).map(JsonPrimitive::new);
        break;
    case Types.BIGINT:
    case Types.FLOAT:
    case Types.REAL:
    case Types.DOUBLE:
    case Types.NUMERIC:
    case Types.DECIMAL:
    case Types.CHAR:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO: " + JDBCType.valueOf(columnType));
    case Types.VARCHAR:
        jsonElement = Optional.ofNullable(resultSet.getString(column)).map(JsonPrimitive::new);
        break;
    case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
    case Types.DATE:
    case Types.TIME:
    case Types.TIMESTAMP:
    case Types.BINARY:
    case Types.VARBINARY:
    case Types.LONGVARBINARY:
    case Types.NULL:
    case Types.OTHER:
    case Types.JAVA_OBJECT:
    case Types.DISTINCT:
    case Types.STRUCT:
    case Types.ARRAY:
    case Types.BLOB:
    case Types.CLOB:
    case Types.REF:
    case Types.DATALINK:
    case Types.BOOLEAN:
    case Types.ROWID:
    case Types.NCHAR:
    case Types.NVARCHAR:
    case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
    case Types.NCLOB:
    case Types.SQLXML:
    case Types.REF_CURSOR:
    case Types.TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE:
    case Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO: " + JDBCType.valueOf(columnType));
    default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown type: " + columnType);
    }
    // If the optional value is missing, assume it's a null
    return jsonElement.orElse(JsonNull.INSTANCE);
}
```

```java
final JsonArray jsonArray = resultSetToJsonArray(resultSet);
System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

Don't forget to close the `resultSet`, of course.

#### JSON streaming

If the `JsonArray` is supposed to be written elsewhere, `JsonWriter` can be a better solution being able to process huge result sets reading row by row and writing JSON element by JSON element.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
static void resultSetToJsonArrayStream(final ResultSet resultSet, final JsonWriter jsonWriter)
        throws SQLException, IOException {
    // Write the [ token
    jsonWriter.beginArray();
    final ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
    while ( resultSet.next() ) {
        // Write row by row
        writeRow(resultSet, jsonWriter, metaData);
    }
    // Finish the array with the ] token
    jsonWriter.endArray();
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
private static void writeRow(final ResultSet resultSet, final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final ResultSetMetaData metaData)
        throws SQLException, IOException {
    final int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    // Similarly to the outer array: the { token starts a new object representing a row
    jsonWriter.beginObject();
    for ( int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
        // Write the column name and try to resolve a JSON literal to be written
        jsonWriter.name(metaData.getColumnName(i));
        writeField(resultSet, jsonWriter, metaData, i);
    }
    // Terminate the object with }
    jsonWriter.endObject();
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
private static void writeField(final ResultSet resultSet, final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final ResultSetMetaData metaData, final int column)
        throws SQLException, IOException {
    final int columnType = metaData.getColumnType(column);
    switch ( columnType ) {
    case Types.BIT:
    case Types.TINYINT:
    case Types.SMALLINT:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO: " + JDBCType.valueOf(columnType));
    case Types.INTEGER:
        jsonWriter.value((Integer) resultSet.getObject(column));
        break;
    case Types.BIGINT:
    case Types.FLOAT:
    case Types.REAL:
    case Types.DOUBLE:
    case Types.NUMERIC:
    case Types.DECIMAL:
    case Types.CHAR:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO: " + JDBCType.valueOf(columnType));
    case Types.VARCHAR:
        jsonWriter.value((String) resultSet.getObject(column));
        break;
    case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
    case Types.DATE:
    case Types.TIME:
    case Types.TIMESTAMP:
    case Types.BINARY:
    case Types.VARBINARY:
    case Types.LONGVARBINARY:
    case Types.NULL:
    case Types.OTHER:
    case Types.JAVA_OBJECT:
    case Types.DISTINCT:
    case Types.STRUCT:
    case Types.ARRAY:
    case Types.BLOB:
    case Types.CLOB:
    case Types.REF:
    case Types.DATALINK:
    case Types.BOOLEAN:
    case Types.ROWID:
    case Types.NCHAR:
    case Types.NVARCHAR:
    case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
    case Types.NCLOB:
    case Types.SQLXML:
    case Types.REF_CURSOR:
    case Types.TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE:
    case Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO: " + JDBCType.valueOf(columnType));
    default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown type: " + columnType);
    }
}
```

Example of writing to `System.out`, but, of course, it can be written anywhere just supplying an appropriate `OutputStream` instance:

```java
final JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))
resultSetToJsonArrayStream(resultSet, jsonWriter);
```

Similarly to `ResultSet`, `JsonWriter` must be closed as well.

I've written the above code for SQLite, but it should work for MySQL too. For example, the test database created and populated with the following SQL statements:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table` (i NUMBER NOT NULL, s TEXT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `table` (i, s) VALUES (1, 'foo');
INSERT INTO `table` (i, s) VALUES (2, 'bar');
INSERT INTO `table` (i, s) VALUES (3, 'baz');
```

will result in

> [{"i":1,"s":"foo"},{"i":2,"s":"bar"},{"i":3,"s":"baz"}]

for both object model and streaming approaches.

Comment: thank you! hm, can you maybe also tell me how i can get a resultset into a JsonObject? As my server application might later need to get many rows. oh wait nm, it seems the function returns an object. :D Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @UwePfeifer Arrays usually deal with it perfectly since arrays hold arbitrary number of elements that are indexed by integer keys automatically. However if you need a result set to be accessible by keys, you can easily implement another function, say `resultSetToJsonObject`, whose main body is just `final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(); for ( int i = 0; resultSet.next(); i++ ) { jsonObject.add(String.valueOf(i), resultSetRowToJsonObject(resultSet, metaData)); } return jsonObject;`. Note that in this case the keys are generated in the loop and do not respect the result set rows PK/FK.

Comment: @UwePfeifer If you want the result set JSON object elements to be identified by PK/FK, then you probably can analyze `ResultSetMetadata` somehow (I'm not sure if it's possible to get such info from a result set). If the result set has PK only, it's easy not to use `String.valueOf(i)`, but extract a PK and convert it to a String since strings are only allowed as keys in JSON objects.

Comment: @UwePfeifer If you also have some FK, then you're probably having hard times, since JSON does not support complex keys. However there are two totally differents ways of accomplish it: you have to invent a way of converting (PK, FK, FK...) tuple to a string (say, just convert the whole tuple to a string), or restructurize the whole result set object to have some intermediate objects representing the (PK, FK, FK...) hierarchy (something like `{"pk1": {"fk1": {"fk2": [row1]}}}` in the result set JSON).

Comment: what is PK/FK? What I want to do is, send a whole table over the network, to a client. then in this client display it in a TableView. What do u mean by Strings are only allowed as keys? does that mean, i can not set a String as value of a for example "notes" column?

Comment: @UwePfeifer PK and FK are primary and foreign keys respectively as commonly used abbreviations. JSON standard allows strings only to be property names in JSON objects, not numbers, arrays, or objects to hold the whole (PK, FK, FK...) value. Values can be arbirtrary: strings, numbers, objects, arrays, or `null`.

Comment: @UwePfeifer If you want to send a whole table over the network, then I strongly recommend you to use `resultSetToJsonArrayStream` -- it can process infinite tables too if those could exist, of course. The idea of streaming is not accumulating `JsonArray` than can waste your application memory, but just read a result set row, and write it to somewhere via `JsonReader`. And yes, I don't think you need `JsonObject`s then since they make little sense in this scenario.

Comment: im writing both the server and the client. and ye, resultSetToJsonArrayStream was what i wanted to use. Thank you very much again. :)

Comment: I guess ill have to read about JsonWriter now, because i also need to know how to recieve the stream on the other end (client). ;)

Comment: @UwePfeifer You need [`JsonReader`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) at the other side. The idea is the same: just _read_ token by token and decide what to do for each result set row.

Comment: can you maybe give me an example of JsonReader reading everything into a collection taht best fits a table structure? I think it's a map? sorry im "self learning" and it's hard for me to understand everything by just a different example. my table structurelooks like: pid (playerid) | uuid (String) | nickName | ... and more ...

Comment: @UwePfeifer Yes, you're almost on a right way: `List<Map<String, Object>>` is a way to go. All you need is just reading with `JsonReader` and reacting on some reading events (see its documentation) where you can decide what to do: create a new result set list, create a result set row map, add a field to the map, etc. This is easy, just believe you can!

Comment: Why do I need a list of string, object? if i wanna put a row for each list entry. is string the column name, and object the object i wanna put in like int, text, date? should we maybe move this to chat? oO

Comment: btw i already have a class, holding players and a playerList. i will add the PlayerList.java and Player.java to the question now (at top). it would be nice if i could populate a playerList with players from the JsonReader? Or should i change something there? sorry for so many questions. i guess this is not too easy.

Comment: hm, i wanna test the client side but first need to fully implement the server. it are just a few columns but, what do i do with Date: case Types.DATE: jsonWriter.value((Date) resultSet.getObject(column)); break; doesnt work. it says for all types is not applicable on compile it says: de/freakyonline/uconeplugin/UCOnePluginServer.java:[198,22] error: no suitable method found for value(Date) - String also doesnt work - i will start a new question about this.

Comment: "Similarly to ResultSet, JsonWriter must be closed as well." if i close jsonWriter, the socket to the server will get closed too. thats not what i want. instead i now did: jsonWriter.endArray();

Comment: @UwePfeifer `close()` and `endArray()` are two different things and serve quite different purposes! The `close()` method closes an I/O resource physically, whilst `endArray()` writes the `]` token, and of course the latter can work if the underlying output stream/writer is open. Close the resource *after* your have written a well-formed JSON document.

Comment: but then my connection to the server closes and i cant send other commands anymore. and i want to stay connected to the server as, live data needs to be processed like, when a player goes off/online.

Comment: what can I do there? Because I need to keep the connection open. reopen a connection on the client side every time? oO